# JQuery - FadeIn + MarginTop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, margin, fadein

I'm trying to get something like this (http://www.hydroholistic.com/, when you hover the logo a box appears fading and animating) what do I have to do for something like that?

Comment: yea you liked one of my websites eh? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot searching for [jQuery Tooltips](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/).

Answer (score 0):

Like Shawn said, try searching for jQuery Tooltips and then just add your own skin/styling. The implementation stays the same however, very easy.